# Count non-letters in string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How to count non letter characters in given string in Javascript, chars like numbers and white spaces, and dashes, all except letters? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a code writing service

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove all letters in the string and check the length of the result:

```js
var a = 'asdflkj12398123!@$!@$1%#$252%$@3 2354 23$%@5$@%$ '
console.log(a.replace(/[a-z]/gi, '').length)
```

Comment: Is `א` a "letter"? ;)

Comment: depending on the language you refer to :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, for which language is `[a-z]` the correct pattern? (hint: not English)

Comment: @georg I gotta say that I'm not sure which languages use exactly the same char-table as the English lang

Comment: There's no such language.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all your normal chars with empty and then you can count on the special characters,Numbers.

```js
let string = "J@s12!r"
string = string.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g,'').length;
console.log(string)
```

Comment: how exactly this answer is different than the one I already gave?

Comment: So I guess you can delete this answer... it's a duplicate

Comment: That's Necessary!

Comment: why is it necessary if it's a duplicate?